# Stm32 and FREERTOS

Tags: stm32, stm32cubemx, freertos

I am a newbie to the embedded world I write this example to learn to programme; I have this problem: I wrote this code but I don't understand it. I have this following situation:

I have two Threads "Led_Green_Task" with normal priority and "Led_Red_Task" with  High priority, and a function "AccessShareData" where I use a semaphore to turn on a LED orange when I start the program I see only the LED orange turned off, I don't understand this situation!

best regards
A.

```
/* definition and creation of Led_Green_Task */
osThreadDef(Led_Green_Task, StartGreenLedTask, osPriorityNormal, 0, 128);
Led_Green_TaskHandle = osThreadCreate(osThread(Led_Green_Task), NULL);

/* definition and creation of Led_Red_Task */
osThreadDef(Led_Red_Task, StartRedLedTask, osPriorityHigh, 0, 128);
Led_Red_TaskHandle = osThreadCreate(osThread(Led_Red_Task), NULL);

/* StartGreenLedTask function */
void StartGreenLedTask(void const * argument)
  {
    /* USER CODE BEGIN StartGreenLedTask */ 
    AccessShareData();
    /* Infinite loop */
    for(;;)
    {
      HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOA,GPIO_PIN_5); // ledgreen  
      vTaskSuspend(Led_Green_TaskHandle);
    }
    /* USER CODE END StartGreenLedTask */
  }

 /* StartRedLedTask function */
 void StartRedLedTask(void const * argument)
 {
   /* USER CODE BEGIN StartRedLedTask */
   AccessShareData();
   /* Infinite loop */
   for(;;)
   {
     HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOA,GPIO_PIN_7);  //led red
     vTaskSuspend(Led_Red_TaskHandle);
   }
   /* USER CODE END StartRedLedTask */
}
/* USER CODE BEGIN Application */
void AccessShareData()
  {
    osSemaphoreWait(CriticalResourceSemaphoreHandle,3000) ; /*acquire token*/

    HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOA,GPIO_PIN_6);   //led orange
    osSemaphoreRelease(CriticalResourceSemaphoreHandle);  //relase token
  }
```

this is the main:

```
    int main(void)
   {
   /* MCU Configuration-----------------------------*/

 /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
 HAL_Init();
 /* Configure the system clock */
 SystemClock_Config();

 /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
 MX_GPIO_Init();
 /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
 /* USER CODE END 2 */
 /* Call init function for freertos objects (in freertos.c) */
 MX_FREERTOS_Init();
 /* Start scheduler */
 osKernelStart(); 
/* We should never get here as control is now taken by the scheduler */
 /* Infinite loop */
 /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
while (1)
{

 /* USER CODE END WHILE */
 /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */

}
/* USER CODE END 3 */
}
```

Comment: do you have the LEDs connected correctly? .... your code is badly formatted, which makes it hard to see the program flow at a glance

Comment: hi jsotola,  tested the connection using tre different task, and  all work well,  i use cubemx for configure the Nucleo stm32L152 and the FreeRtos, i i write you only freertos.c file because in the main  i don't write nothing

Comment: I see you suspend all the tasks, can you explain how they are supposed to wake up again?

Comment: Also, start with something simple. Write a program which blinks LEDs from a loop, then move to a program which blinks a LED from a task. When you get those basic things working, try using a semaphore.

Comment: hi to all i fix it, now all work well